# hugo url content organization not working

Tags: hugo, hugo-content-organization

[error example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8YiN.png)

[file structure I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEDFP.png)

I am using the content organization guidelines described by the hugo website and it seems to not work whenever I run `hugo server -D`. any suggestions as to how I could get it to work?

this is the structure offered by the hugo docs just in case:

```
.
└── content
    └── about
    |   └── index.md  // <- https://example.com/about/
    ├── posts
    |   ├── firstpost.md   // <- https://example.com/posts/firstpost/
    |   ├── happy
    |   |   └── ness.md  // <- https://example.com/posts/happy/ness/
    |   └── secondpost.md  // <- https://example.com/posts/secondpost/
    └── quote
        ├── first.md       // <- https://example.com/quote/first/
        └── second.md      // <- https://example.com/quote/sec
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the difference between index.md and _index.md? You must use the latter in this case.

https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/what-is-the-difference-between-index-md-and-index-md/10330

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, but it still doesn't work, I've found out that for some reason the other pages will only render if I modify the file while the server is running. It still gives me an error if I don't refresh.

Comment: That is a glitch... it is not working because it interprets the files as resources instead of pages. This has to do with directories being Sections or not.

Comment: When I deploy it it doesn't seem to work either. Any tips for that? I'm sorry I'm very new to hugo so I'm still not well versed in how it works

Comment: Is there any way to fix the glitch? It's proving to be a big problem.

Comment: If you share your repo I can fix it for you.

Comment: https://github.com/CowWorks/CowWorks-Improved I appreciate the help

Comment: The index.md in content should be _index.md

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: I stopped using the file as the welcome page and just used the homepage template feature, but I still can't get the routing to work. This is the code as of now: https://github.com/CowWorks/CowWorks-Improved/commit/939a705ecc7a6b5f88120494bb4a74b4f48bb358

Comment: Hmmmm. Apparently it works now that I have reworked the homepage. I am not sure on what made the difference.